# Test accounts created for a Facebook application not able to login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

From today morning onwards I am experiencing an issue with test user accounts in Facebook. I am not able to login into Facebook application with the newly created test user accounts. But I am able to login with old/existing test accounts.

Any idea why I am facing this issue . By any chance Facebook having issues related to authenticating test user accounts? Let me know.

Thanks,
Narendra

Comment: I think there was a bug reported today about it. Try to search developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Yes, you are right. Bug ID is :: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1483024908596533/